# Use url instead of get

Tags: php, url, get

I have a question on my website I'm trying to create pages for reading the news like a blog but I', having a problem I don't want to the url to look like this "http://website.com/post.php?id=1" instead I want something like this "http://website.com/post/news_title" and other example 
"website.com/admin/posts/new" insted of "website.com/admin/new-post.php"

Any Ideas? I don't even know how to start to look.

Comment: Type "URL rewriting" in Google - start there.

Comment: use .htaccess to achieve this

Comment: Google friendly or clean url + php.

Comment: Enter the realm of URL rewriting. I'd recommend [this](http://mod-rewrite-cheatsheet.com/) and [this](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/).

Comment: You can use this http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/890307-url-use-instead-send-variables

Comment: Thanks for all the help. This will be enought to start